# Extend/Hide Row with multiple child table

Tags: jquery, .net

I have a datatable with Extend/Hide Row, which is working fine with single child table, but I want to show multiple tables when user click on extend button of main datatable

[Please see the Image once for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA43H.png)

For single I am using -

```
    var mytr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var myrow = dataTable.row(mytr);
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (myrow.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        myrow.child.hide();
        mytr.removeClass('shown');
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        myrow.child(format(myrow.data())).show();
        mytr.addClass('shown');
    }
```

Comment: That's seems to be an Excel sheet. What does it have to do with jquery and net?

Comment: just to visualize what I am looking for I used excel, but in originally my main datatable is designed using cshtml and both child tables in .js

Comment: I found solution by my own -                                                                           
                row.child([
                format(row.data()).after('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>'),
                newformat(row.data())
            ])
                .show();